Custom context menu with fade transition in JavaScript
I've been trying to create a custom context menu with some buttons in it, however there is a problem. I have an opacity transition, and it only runs once when I right click. The next times I right click the menu will show up but without the opacity transition.
Here is my code:
HTML:
<div id="contextMenuDesktop">
    <ul>
        <!-- Some elements here -->
    </ul>
</div>

JavaScript:
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(!menuOpened) {
        document.getElementById("contextMenuDesktop").style.opacity = "0";
        setInterval(function() {
                document.getElementById("contextMenuDesktop").style.opacity = "1";
        }, 100); // It has to be run few milliseconds after, for some reason
        document.getElementById("contextMenuDesktop").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("contextMenuDesktop").style.left = `${e.pageX}px`;
        document.getElementById("contextMenuDesktop").style.top = `${e.pageY}px`;
}});

CSS:
#contextMenuDesktop {
    transition: opacity 500ms;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 375px;
    width: 175px;
    background-color: rgba(100,100,100,.6);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 3px lightgray;
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    display: none;
    
}

I believe the problem is that the line that sets the opacity to 0 doesn't have time to finish, and after only 100 milliseconds it has to be visible again, so the transition doesn't work. Does somebody know the answer?

Basically the problem is that you apply display: block at the same time you apply opacity: 1 and therefor you need your call to setTimeout (meaning your initial reasoning why it does not work is correct). This solution works a bit different in pushing the contextmenu element via z-index: -1 behind the <html> element to avoid display altogether.
My solution does not modify inline styles and instead works by utilizing CSS classes. I also changed a few things in your JS to avoid unneeded DOM traversals and make the code itself a bit more readable (IMHO). I've added thorough comments so you can understand it.


const contextMenu = document.getElementById("contextMenuDesktop"); // <-- save a element reference once and omit the re-occuring DOM traversals

document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (!contextMenu.classList.contains("is--opened")) { // <-- check if the menu is already opened
    contextMenu.classList.add("is--opened");           // <-- add "is--opened" class if not
  }
  // I moved the position updates outside the opened check to make
  // subsequent "contextmenu"-events reposition the element. If you
  // don't want that, move them back into the "if"
  contextMenu.style.left = `${e.pageX}px`;
  contextMenu.style.top = `${e.pageY}px`;
});



// I added the below code for demo purposes so that you can close 
// the context menu
contextMenu.addEventListener('click', function () {
  contextMenu.classList.remove("is--opened");
});
#contextMenuDesktop {
    transition: opacity 500ms;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 375px;
    width: 175px;
    background-color: rgba(100,100,100,.6);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 3px lightgray;
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1; /* changed, pushes the element behind/below the page */
    /* display: none; */
}

#contextMenuDesktop.is--opened {
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 1;
}
<div id="contextMenuDesktop">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>



